# SQL count size and gender

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I would like to count shirt size and each size must show different gender

Here is output I want to see

```
Size Qty Male Female 

S    20   15     5
M    30   20    10
```

Here is my some SQL language and PHP code, but this's query only qty of each size.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT ssize,COUNT(*) FROM students GROUP BY ssize");

$stmt->execute();

<?php while($rs = $stmt->fetch()) { ?>

    <?=$rs['ssize']." ".number_format($rs["COUNT(*)"])?> 

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: give more detail of question  what is ssize ?

Comment: You might want to add the table (data), which you are querying, as well - preferably as [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: What does your table (students) looks like?

Comment: What is ssize? pleas give more details

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT s.ssize, COUNT(*),
       SUM(s.gender = 'M') as Male, SUM(s.gender = 'F') as Female
FROM students s
GROUP BY s.ssize;
```